# Dynamic table names

Tags: sql-server, datatypes, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create dynamic table names for each month.

This is how I tried it:

```
    declare @query varchar(max)
    declare @i date
    declare @tableid int
    declare @tblname varchar(20)

    declare @fulltablename varchar(50)

    set @tblname = 'tblLoan_'

    set @i = '07/01/2019'

    while @i <= (select max(Approval_date) from tblLoan)
    begin
    set @tableid = month(@i)
    set @fulltablename = @tblname+ cast(@tableid as varchar)


    set @query = '(select * into ['+@fulltablename+'] from  tblLoan 
    where 
    Approval_date <= '+ @i + ')'
    execute (@query)
    set @i = dateadd(month, +1, @i)

    end

I am getting this error:
```

```
Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.
```

After concentrating `@i` variable:

```
declare @query varchar(max)
    declare @i date
    declare @tableid int
    declare @tblname varchar(20)

declare @fulltablename varchar(50)

set @tblname = 'tblLoan_'

set @i = '07/01/2019'

while @i <= (select max(Approval_date) from tblLoan)
begin
set @tableid = month(@i)
set @fulltablename = @tblname+ cast(@tableid as varchar)


set @query = '(select * into ['+@fulltablename+'] from  tblLoan 
where 
Approval_date <= '+ convert(varchar(10),@i) + ')'
execute (@query)
set @i = dateadd(month, +1, @i)

end
```

Now I am getting this for every loop:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int
```

I got an exam like this in my course. I am taking a course for data analytics.

Is this a bad idea to implement in a data warehouse? If yes, why?

Comment: See also https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `@i` to a character datatype before you can concatenate it into the `@query` variable.

Example with a `print` statement included and the `exec` commented out

```
declare @tblLoan table (Approval_date date)
insert into @tblLoan(Approval_date) values('2019-08-01')
declare @query varchar(max)
declare @i date
declare @tableid int
declare @tblname varchar(20)

declare @fulltablename varchar(50)

set @tblname = 'tblLoan_'

set @i = '07/01/2019'

while @i <= (select max(Approval_date) from @tblLoan)
begin
set @tableid = month(@i)
set @fulltablename = @tblname+ cast(@tableid as varchar)


set @query = '(select * into ['+@fulltablename+'] from  tblLoan 
where 
Approval_date <= '+ convert(varchar(10),@i) + ')'
print @query
--execute (@query)
set @i = dateadd(month, +1, @i)

end
```

---

```
(1 row affected)
(select * into [tblLoan_7] from  tblLoan 
where 
Approval_date <= 2019-07-01)
(select * into [tblLoan_8] from  tblLoan 
where 
Approval_date <= 2019-08-01)
```

---

To get around the operand clash error between `int` and `datetime2`, alter your dynamic code to ensure your `@i` date is wrapped in quotes:

`Approval_date <= '''+ convert(varchar(10),@i) + ''')'`

Example:

```
create table tblLoan (Approval_date date)
insert into tblLoan(Approval_date) values('2019-08-01')
declare @query varchar(max)
    declare @i date
    declare @tableid int
    declare @tblname varchar(20)

declare @fulltablename varchar(50)

set @tblname = 'tblLoan_'

set @i = '07/01/2019'

while @i <= (select max(Approval_date) from tblLoan)
begin
set @tableid = month(@i)
set @fulltablename = @tblname+ cast(@tableid as varchar)


set @query = '(select * into ['+@fulltablename+'] from  tblLoan 
where 
Approval_date <= '''+ convert(varchar(10),@i) + ''')'
print @query
execute (@query)
set @i = dateadd(month, +1, @i)

end
```